# specify function in ASP.NET binding expression

Tags: asp.net, .net, binding, repeater

A repeater control is bound to array of items with class that has boolean IsClosed property. I want to display one picture if it is true, and another if it is false. I can't just add a property to my item class that would return the exact path to the image, so I need some sort of function that would process IsClosed property for each data item inside Repeater's DataSource. But how do I write a proper binding expression? Code like:

```
<%# Eval("IsClosed") %>
```

works, but code like:

```
<%# GetIconPath(Eval("IsClosed")) %>
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
<%# GetIconPath((bool)Eval("IsClosed")) %>
```

Comment: what bool means in this answer?  if there was string format what expression shuld be used instead of bool?

Comment: @DavidPeterson "Eval" returns something of type "object". "(bool)" coerces the object into a bool, which is the type of argument expected by GetIconPath. Otherwise, GetIconPath would choke on an argument of type "object".